# Python image multiple crops with Pillow and grouped and displayed in a row with Bokeh

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, bokeh

I have the following task: generate multiple image crops, and then display them grouped in rows next to each other. 
So far I managed to generates crops based on coordinates. I have no clue how to display the images in rows, grouped by 'User' and ordered by 'Time'. I should use Bokeh for plotting the images, because there will be more plots to integrate. Please help!!!!

The dataframe:

```
#Import libraries
import numpy as np
from numpy import asarray
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib as plt

#Create the dataframe
data = {'Time':  ['2586', '2836', '2986', '3269', '3702'],
        'Map': ['Buc.jpg', 'Buc.jpg', 'Buc.jpg', 'Buc.jpg', 'Buc.jpg'],
        'Index': ['9', '10', '11', '12', '13'],
        'PSize': ['250', '150', '283', '433', '183'],
        'X': ['751', '673', '542', '762', '624'],
        'Y': ['458', '316', '287', '303', '297'],
        'User': ['u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2', 'u2'],
        }

columns = ['Time','Map','Index','PSize','X','Y','User']

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = columns)
df = df.astype(dtype= {"Time":"int64", "Map":"object","Index":"int64", 'PSize':'int64', 'X': 'int64', 'Y':"int64", 'User':'object'})
df.head()
```

Image file:
[image]

Generate the crops based on coordinates:

```
#Create coordinate and crop the image
imagefile = 'Buc.jpg'
coordinates = list(df[['X', 'Y']].itertuples(index=False, name=None))
psize = 100

img = Image.open(imagefile)
for x, y in coordinates:
      box = (x-psize/2, y-psize/2, x+psize/2, y+psize/2)
      img.crop(box).show('%s.x%03d.y%03d.jpg'% (imagefile.replace('.jpg',''), x, y))
```

Output example:

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "grouped by 'User' and ordered by 'Time'". Can you provide an example of how the desired output should look like?

Comment: I've just upload an image as example. The small images are displayed per users. In this case we have only 2, u1 and u2. The order in which the images are displayed is "Time" order, but also can be the 'Index" (see the columns in the dataframe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Note that `Buc.jpg` must be available within the current working directory when you run the script.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import FixedTicker, FuncTickFormatter, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [2586, 2836, 2986, 3269, 3702],
                   'X': [751, 673, 542, 762, 624],
                   'Y': [458, 316, 287, 303, 297],
                   'User': ['u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2', 'u2']})

imagefile = 'Buc.jpg'
coordinates = list(df[['X', 'Y']].itertuples(index=False, name=None))
psize = 100

img = Image.open(imagefile).convert('RGBA')
cropped_images = []
for x, y in coordinates:
    box = (x - psize / 2, y - psize / 2, x + psize / 2, y + psize / 2)
    cropped_images.append(np.array(img.crop(box)).view(np.uint32)[::-1])

df['Image'] = cropped_images

# There's probably a better method to populate `TimeCoord` which I don't know.
df = df.sort_values('Time')
df['TimeCoord'] = 0
for u in df['User'].unique():
    udf = (df['User'] == u)
    df.loc[udf, 'TimeCoord'] = np.arange(udf.sum())

user_coords = dict(zip(df['User'].unique(), range(df.shape[0])))
df['UserCoord'] = df['User'].replace(user_coords)

p = figure(match_aspect=True)
for r in [p.xaxis, p.xgrid, p.ygrid]:
    r.visible = False

# Manually creating a categorical-like axis to make sure that we can use `dodge` below.
p.yaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=list(user_coords.values()))
p.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(args=dict(rev_user_coords={v: k for k, v in user_coords.items()}),
                                      code="return rev_user_coords[tick];")


ds = ColumnDataSource(df)
img_size = 0.8
p.image_rgba(image='Image',
             x=dodge('TimeCoord', -img_size / 2), y=dodge('UserCoord', -img_size / 2),
             dw=img_size, dh=img_size, source=ds)
p.rect(x='TimeCoord', y='UserCoord', width=img_size, height=img_size, source=ds,
       line_dash='dashed', fill_alpha=0)
show(p)
```

Comment: Just great, thank you! It looks like is what I expected to get. The only thing that is not working is users ordering on yaxis.